# How do I setup a QNX project to generate debug executable?

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino

I imported an existing code base, which was setup for QNX into QNX Momentics.  Using v6.5 of the OS with Service Pack 1.

Everything out there in the tutorials about debugging say to turn on a Variant, but my project settings doesn't have a section for Variants.

Where would I create the flag to generate the debug runtime?

Answer (score 1):

In QNX Momentics you need to right click on the project (from the Project Explorer window) and select "Properties". In the list on the left side of the properties window choose the "QNX C/C++ Project" item. The right side of the properties window will show a multi-tabbed set of properties. The second tab is "Build Variants". Select it. Make sure you have both the release and debug variant ticked for your target hardware, you might need to expand the target type.

For example, "X86 (Little Endian)" has two child items for "debug" and "release".

The other thing you might need to make sure of is that when you create your "Debug Configuration" to execute the application with the debugger is that you use the debug variant as the application to launch - it should have a "_g" suffix.